# Using "know" instead of "find out"

Tags: word-usage

Is using "know" instead of "find out" idiomatic here?

- Know who did this to him and bring them to me!

Comment: Why do you think it might be idiomatic? Have you seen or heard the word **know** used as a synonym for "discover"?  I can say to you *Know this material, or fail the exam.* But it doesn't mean "discover" or even "learn". It means "To pass the exam, you must know this material."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least to me, somehow, the word *know* does not show any *efforts*. It simply says that one should have *knowledge* of something. In addition, I have seldom come across a sentence that begins with *'Know'* unless it's a super-informal talk.

On the other hand, *find out* requires your efforts *to know* the matter. Thus, if you want to investigate and know the truth, you better use *find out* over  plain *know.*